# Short dropouts while playing audio from microphone

Tags: java, c#, audio, microphone, voice

I'm actually trying to make my own VoiceChat for game. So I decided to try first to get audio data from microphone and play it directly to the speakers.
I've done it in Java and C# but in both languages, in both after starting the record there is a dropout after about 0.5 seconds for about 0.25 seconds, after that dropout the audio works normally.

I'm using this code in C#, have I done something wrong?

```
using System;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace VoiceChat
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mic = false;
            
            var recorder = new WaveInEvent
            {
                WaveFormat = new WaveFormat(96000, 2),
                BufferMilliseconds = 10,
                NumberOfBuffers = 10
            };
            var sound = new BufferedWaveProvider(recorder.WaveFormat);
            var playback = new WaveOutEvent();

            recorder.StartRecording();
            playback.Init(sound);
            playback.Play();
            
            recorder.DataAvailable += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                if (mic)
                {
                    sound.AddSamples(eventArgs.Buffer, 0, eventArgs.BytesRecorded);
                }
            };

            while (true)
            {
                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.A))
                {
                    mic = !mic;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I've added a switch to it and everytime I turn on the audio with this switch the same as described happens)

Thanks!